# Cannot update/get any packages. gedit not installed

Tags: 14.04, apt, gedit

my problem is that my sources.list is out of date for some reason. I already found the fix in another port, but it doesn't work. It says to use gedit to edit sources.list and replace everything with the proper sources. Well, for some reason I don't have it installed (Ubuntu Server 14.04) and I can't install it or else I get the main problem again.

Failed to fetch http:// some ubuntu site Could not resolve hostname "us.archive.ubuntu.com"

Is there any other way to edit sources.list? Or do I need to do a re-install of the OS?

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal type:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are for WriteOut and Exit. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

You could also use vim instead of nano, but nano is easier to use.

Comment: I copied the whole document by hand, and then used ctrl + o to save and of course. No such file /ect/apt/sources.list

Comment: Try making and editing an example file: `cd /tmp && sudo touch example-file && sudo nano example-file`. Write anything to example-file, save and exit and then use `cat example-file` to show what you wrote to example-file. Do you get any error message like: `No such file /tmp/example-file`?

Comment: No, it works as expected. I'm thinking of just re-installing the OS as this is a fresh install anyways. Thanks for all your help by the way.

Comment: If nano is working as expected, you should also check if a file with path /etc/apt/sources.list exists. If not, then you can make one using the command `cd /etc/apt/ && touch sources.list`. This command will either create a new sources.list file in /etc/apt/ if a sources.list file does not already exist or else do nothing if a sources.list file already exists in /etc/apt/

Comment: Ok, I re-installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 and now the sources.list is there and filled out. But I am still getting the error when trying t o install/update packages.

Comment: Open your source.list using `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`. Find `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` and replace it with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`. Then run the command `sudo apt-get update` to update your package list of available software from the new software sources.

Comment: I can't edit sources.list for some reason. Permission denied, but this account should be root shouldn't it? Is there a way to make myself a root user?

edit: figured it out

edit2: problem still persists after removing 'us' from needed places

Comment: For security reasons you normally run as a regular user in Ubuntu. You can use the `sudo` command to run a single command as root. Alternatively you can use the `sudo su` command to become a root user in the terminal. The command prompt will change from a $ character to a # character indicating that you are a root user. If you are a root user, use the command `exit` to go back to being a regular user. 2. I checked http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu and it is alive, so check if you have network connectivity on your server generally.

Comment: It just occurred to me that maybe me using wireless would be the problem. I'll re-install using Ethernet and hopefully that should resolve any issues.